# How do I get the count value from this SQL statement

Tags: jquery, sql, database

I'm playing around with webSQL and I have a table named **products** with the fields **id**, **product**, **category**.

I've executed the following SQL

```
SELECT category, COUNT(*) FROM products GROUP BY category
```

which returns data with two columns, the first named category which lists each individual category which I can output using:

```
list.find('#name').text(record.category);
```

The second column returned is the count of each record that belongs in the category and the name of that columns appears as **COUNT(*)**. So naturally I tried the following to get the count:

```
list.find('#number').text(record.COUNT(*));
```

However the error returned is

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

This seems like it should be rather straight forward however I don't seem to be able to find the answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should need an alias for your count(*) like this: count(*) as prodCount or something you want it to be called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add an `ALIAS` and use that to fetch the columnName

```
SELECT category, COUNT(*) totalCount 
FROM   products 
GROUP  BY category
```

then

```
list.find('#number').text(record.totalCount);
```

Comment: That's brilliant thanks for the quick reply, exactly what I needed!.. Won't let me accept your reply as an answer for another 10 mins.

Answer (score 0):

Mmm the problem is that the sentence

```
list.find('#number').text(record.COUNT(*));
```

It's not valid because that's not a column name, just add the name of the count(*) to the SQL sentence like this:

```
SELECT category, COUNT(*) as qnty FROM products GROUP BY category
```

Then extract the data like this:

```
list.find('#number').text(record.qnty);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request is not working because you forget to use an alias for COUNT(*) :

```
SELECT category, COUNT(*) AS tCount FROM products GROUP BY category

list.find('#number').text(record.tCount);
```